# Does pack apply to nested objects and structs

Tags: c++11, gcc, arm, embedded

While working on an ARM Cortex-M4 with gcc the following situation has arisen. To reduce the RAM footprint of the software I am looking into using `pack`. The following example details a class with a templated variable holing many different variables.

```cpp
#pragma pack(push,4)
template<class TYPE>
class foo 
{
  public:
    // Normal functions

  private:
    TYPE bar;
    // Some other variables.

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Will the `pack` property work for the variables in `TYPE` or only on the padding around `bar`?

One must imagine the class foo is stored in an array of considerable size.

When tried this gave only a marginal improvement. I could not deduct if this was due to the posibility TYPE had no benefits from `pack` or only the variables in the class `foo` where packed.

Comment: What do your experiments reveal? I'd assume that just `foo` will be packed.

Comment: A yes I will include this in the question.

Comment: Use some simple tests with array of these types, and look into the listing and/or map files to find out. -- Additionally, an alignment of "4" will not give you a good improvement, depending on the specific variable types. Did you try smaller values? -- [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas) is quite clear: "_GCC supports a set of #pragma directives that change the maximum alignment of members of structures (other than zero-width bit-fields), unions, and classes **subsequently defined**._" (emphasis by me)

Comment: Will set up an example later, I used production code to do the initial tests. It is not straight forward to do an objective evaluation it it.

Comment: pack is a bad thing, did you already reduce space by re-arranging the order that variables are defined? you can get the same results in a non-risky way.

Comment: For a seldom used class, you could actually increase memory usage.  The compiler may need temporaries to access the data, it could increase stack use and it will definitely increase code size.  Pack  is best used for serialization (although other (better?) methods exist).  If you have many instances (many new/delete), it might make sense to pack those.  You would be better off to look at `const` and POD (plain old data) which allows classes to be placed in ROM/Flash.

Comment: @old_timer - pack isn't *always* a bad thing.  Sometimes it is the only way to create a struct to interface with hw, say, memory-mapped io (though I tend to prefer other methods than structs, but a lot of coworkers have disagreed with me :-) )

Comment: If you declare, say, `MyTtype x; foo<MyType> y;` then it is necessary that `sizeof(x) == sizeof(y.bar);` . It's impossible for `MyType` to magically take less space inside `foo` than outside. In other words, the size and layout of the type is determined when that type is defined, not when it's used.

Comment: You need to use pack around the definition of each relevant struct.  Or, as others have suggested, use a different approach than pack.  I can't remember a time when I used 'pack' to reduce the RAM footprint...

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I've just added something important. The class foo in my case is used in an array. Any reduction in the overal size is thus apricated.

Comment: As old_timer mentioned, you can get much of this benefit without pack, by properly arranging the elements of each struct or class.

Comment: @old_timer and basya I see this as a very reasonable action, unfortunately in my practical case the code of TYPE is generated.